# Averaging list duplicated elements

Tags: r, list, dictionary, key

I have the following list containing duplicate names

```
> l
$A
[1] 2

$A
[1] 4

$B
[1] 10
```

I can't find a way to merge the "A" elements into a single "A" averaging the value of these elements. The resulting list should be as follows

```
> l
$A
[1] 3

$B
[1] 10
```

Is there a way to produce this list?

Comment: Something like `tapply(unlist(l),names(l),mean)`? Assuming you really have a list whose elements are really just all single numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, stack(li), FUN = mean)
```

---

If we need it in a `list`, then do a `split` and loop through the `list` to get the `mean`

```
lapply(split(li, names(li)), function(x) mean(unlist(x)))
#$A
#[1] 3

#$B
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
li <- list(A = 2, A = 4, B = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

li <- list(A = 2, A = 4, B = 2)

tibble(key = names(li), value = unlist(li)) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(value))
```